# The correct usage of c# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

I've built an application which essentially comes in and out of focus when the user has satisfied the global hook, what i want to know (and i apologise if this is a duplicate) is creating a new instance of a form and showing it to the user which could be done many times during the applications lifetime, is this creating the same form many times in memory?

Any guidance would be much appreciated on disposing correctly of forms, what would be best is creating one form instance and only showing that form during the applications lifetime, perhaps a class level form instance?

Comment: I've noticed this mainly down to during running the form, the Private Memory Set shown in task manager related to the application gradually increases as i bring the application in and out of focus!

Comment: How often do you hide/show the form? Did you try inserting a GC.Collect() to see if the memory is only temporarily lost (until the garbage collector is run)

Comment: you see this can be done an infinite amount of times depending on how many times the user uses it until they exit or shut down their machine, i havent, isnt calling the GC bad practise, will look into it though for trying to find the leak...

Comment: yes, it's bad practice, but I'm saying to use it to see if you have a real memory leak or if the memory isn't collected yet. as a debugging tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the form instances you created will be automatically garbage collected when they are closed and no longer referenced from any code (keep an eye out for even handlers). So it shouldn't be a problem.

**Edit:** However if you often show and hide the form and you can easily change the code to make it use the same formular then go for it, because sometimes memory leaks are difficult to recognize, especially in case of events, etc.